# Can I travel to UK on a tourist visa after I apply for a Global Talent visa?

Tags: visas, uk, tourist-visas

If I apply to a UK Global Talent visa from outside of the UK, is it possible to go to the UK as a tourist afterwards? Here I mean a proper tourist trip without any intentions of staying in the UK illegally.

What is the chance of denied entry to the UK on a tourist visa? Or even banning from further entries? (Let's assume I have received tourist visa long time ago before I even planned to apply to a Global Talent visa).

Will the entry chance depend on the Global Talent visa submission status?

- if the submission is in process
- if the submission has been already supported (i.e., the Global Talent visa is going to be granted if all further conditions are met)
- if the submission has been already declined

Or what should be the general recommendation for Global Talent applicants, should they abstain from **any tourist visits** to the UK?

Comment: What do you mean by a ‘tourist visa’? If you have a valid visitor visa, there should be no problem in using it during its validity period. Or do you mean ‘visa-free entry’ as a tourist?

Comment: @Traveller I mean a visitor visa which has been issued for a tourist trip. I assume that the border officer may have doubts about purpose of visit to the UK (i.e., can suspect that I have no intention to leave the UK) if I have submitted an immigration visa application.